# spring mvc servlet initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, initialization

I am new to spring MVC. I am looking for a place in my spring mvc applicationwhere I can initialize all sorts of things in the application.
usually I did that in the init() method of the my main servlet but now the dispatcher servlet is of spring and I cannot overide the init function.

what is the best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `ServletContextListener` and define it in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.company.YourListenerClass</listener-class>
</listener>
```

(you make a class which implements `ServletContextListener` and implement the `contextInitialized()` method, where you place your initialization code)

Comment: Thanks it works.
Is this a common practice for initialization?

Comment: yes, it is. The interface is in the servlet API and is meant exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

All beans can have an init-method. See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html). I suppose that the best practice will be to use this method for every bean you define. A bean can have references to other beans if this is required.