# Spring Web Application: Post-DispatcherServlet initialization

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, initialization, startup

I am using Spring 3.2 `DispatcherServlet`.  I am looking for an initialization hook that takes place *after* the `DispatcherServlet` initialization completes; either a standard Spring solution or servlet solution.  Any suggestions?

As a point of reference, the final logging statements after servlet startup follow.  I want my initialization method to execute right after the `configured successfully` [log statement](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean.java#L139).

```
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'mySpringDispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.mySpringDispatcherServlet] 
INFO  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'mySpringDispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 5000 ms   
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Servlet 'mySpringDispatcherServlet' configured successfully
```

From my research, so far the following have **not** had the desired effect:

1. Extending `ContextLoaderListener`/implementing `ServletContextListener` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2006049/237225).
2. Implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` per [the javaoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html).
3. My beans use `@PostConstruct` successfully; I'm looking for a Servlet or container level hook that will be executed essentially after the container initializes and post-processes the beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root issue was that I couldn't override the `final` method [`HttpsServlet.init()`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/HttpServletBean.java#L116).  I found a nearby `@Override`-able method in `DispatcherServlet.initWebApplicationContext` that ensured my beans and context were fully initialized:

```
@Override
protected WebApplicationContext initWebApplicationContext()
{
    WebApplicationContext wac = super.initWebApplicationContext();

    // do stuff with initialized Foo beans via:
    // wac.getBean(Foo.class);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Don't do it like that, as that is a really bad way. As mentioned in other posts the ideal place for this is an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` which gets fired as soon as the context has finished loading. So instead of doing in that class and create the custom dispatcher servlet, just add a listener.

Answer (score 1):

From Spring's **[Standard and Custom Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events)**.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextListener implements
                                     ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ApplicationContext was initialized or refreshed: "
                               + event.getApplicationContext().getDisplayName());
    }

}
```

The event above will be fired when the DispatcherServlet is initialized, such as when it prints:

```
INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'ServletName': initialization completed in 1234 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>` within your application context. This event listener will then be called once for your *root context* and once for each *servlet context*.

```
public class StartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
        ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext) event.getSource();
        System.out.println("Context '" + context.getDisplayName() + "' started.");
    }

}
```

If you define this listener within your *servlet context*, it should be called just once for the servlet context intself.

Comment: I registered my `StartupListener` in my web.xml, but I get a RTE "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCircularityError: com/sun/beans/WeakCache".

Comment: I also couldn't find a way to declare the listener in my `<servlet>` declaration--a `<listener>` can only be declared under `<web-app>`, right?  How do I make it specific to the servlet context?

Comment: You need to declare that in Spring servlet context... if you are using XML config, then put it there as a `<bean>` declaration. This has nothing to do with the standard based JEE Servlet listeners.

Answer (score 0):

try this, change your port number.
In my case i changed from  server.port=8001 to server.port=8002