# Extending The Spring Framework (Java) Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I'm working on a Java web app that uses the Spring Framework (MVC).  All my code is in controller files that are instantiated by the servlet.  I would like to extend the servlet so that I can run some code in the `init` of the servlet; however, I'm very new to the Spring Framework and Java web development in general.  I'm not sure how to extend the servlet, where I would put my derived servlet, etc.  Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006022/spring-mvc-servlet-initialization and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419695/init-method-in-spring-controller-annotation-version

Comment: Can you specify what you're trying to do? Maybe it can be achieved in a simpler way

Comment: I would like to run a single background process which any request can pass long-term work to.  See the 'Background Processing' section at [http://oreilly.com/catalog/jservlet/chapter/ch03.html].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean dispatcherServlet? you can just extends this servlet, re-config it in web.xml.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Your DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with defining code in an XML file.  How would I add code to the derived servlet's init function?  Is there no way to extend the dispatcherServlet using a traditional class file (.java)?

Comment: Of course you can extend the DispatcherServlet. The answer is telling how to register your custom DispatcherServlet in the web container. Note the "Your DispatcherServlet".